# Async method has wrong return type

Tags: c#, async-await, task

```
MyViewModel
{
    SetProxyService()   //gets called on app init
    {
        ConnectorProxy.SetMethod(SignIn);  **//Error: 'Task<string>MyViewModel.SignIn(string, string)' has the wrong return type**
    }

    private async Task<string> SignIn(string uname, string password)
    {
        string resultData = "failed";
        bool isSuccess = await objService.Login(uname, password);
        if (isSuccess)
        {
           resultData = "success";
        }
        return resultData;
    }
}


class ConnectorProxy
{
    private Func<string, string, string> _signIn;
 
    public string SignIn(string uname, string password) // Gets called outside app
    {
        return _signIn(uname, password);
    }

    public void SetMethod(Func<string, string, string> signin)
    {
       _signIn = signin;
    }
}
```

I am getting the compilation error from MyViewModel.cs:

> Error CS0407  'Task MyViewModel.SetMethod(string, string)' has the wrong return type

EDIT - I need to return resultData (as string) from MyVieModel.SignIn to  ConnectorProxy.SignIn. Please suggest a right approach.

Comment: `SignIn` has the return type `Task<string>` and `SetMethod` takes a Function with the return type of `string`. Those are not the same.

Comment: How is `MyViewModel{ SetProxyService() { ... } }` valid C#?

Comment: @Igor I tried,

       `public void SetMethod(Func<string, string, Task<string>> signin)
        {
            _signIn = signin;
        }`

Error - **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<string, string, System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>>' to 'System.Func<string, string, string>' **


Please suggest correct approach.

Comment: It is not just one change, you need to change all the code that relies on the return type. Mixing and matching async code with sync code in a call stack is almost never a good idea. Use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Side note: I removed the TPL tag, that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: What is the application type? Is it a console app? A .net web api app? A wcf app? What is this included in?

Comment: .net web api app

Comment: So you should be using async all the way. Change everything to use `Task<string>` and make your web api entry point asynchronous as well.

Comment: How is `ConnectorProxy.SetMethod(SignIn);` valid when `SetMethod` is not marked `static`? From what you've shown, `ConnectorProxy` is a type, so that makes it a static method call.

Comment: As for the new error, you also need to change the type of `_signIn` to match the new type of the `signin` parameter. When you applied Igor's advice, you only did it halfway.

Comment: Should be `public void SetMethod(Func<string, string, Task<string>> signin)` etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the return type to `Task<string>` and modified SignIn method,

```
public string SignIn(string uname, string password)     {
        return _signIn(uname, password).Result;
}
```